# Шифрование в php и powershell. Получить один результат

Tags: php, криптография, powershell, decrypt

появилась задача зашифровать текст на сервере (php) и расшифровать его скриптом powershell. 
Пытаюсь найти общие функции для шифрования/дешифрования по ключу. Ничего рабочего найти не могу. 
Различные костыли кода с Rijndael256ECB в PS и mcrypt_encrypt в php дают разный результат.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что можно использовать?
Мой не рабочий код (найдено на просторах интернета):

powershell( PS v.4 Win7)

```
function Encrypt-Rijndael256ECB {
    param(
        [byte[]]$Key,
        [string]$Plaintext
    )

    $RijndaelProvider = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged

    # Set block size to 256 to imitate MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256
    $RijndaelProvider.BlockSize = 256
    # Make sure we use ECB mode, or the generated IV will fuck up the first block upon decryption
    $RijndaelProvider.Mode      = [System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode]::ECB
    $RijndaelProvider.Key       = $key

    # This object will take care of the actual cryptographic transformation
    $Encryptor = $RijndaelProvider.CreateEncryptor()

    # Set up a memorystream that we can write encrypted data back to
    $EncMemoryStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
    $EncCryptoStream = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream -ArgumentList $EncMemoryStream,$Encryptor,"Write"
    $EncStreamWriter = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter -ArgumentList $EncCryptoStream

    # When we write data back to the CryptoStream, it'll get encrypted and written back to the MemoryStream
    $EncStreamWriter.Write($Plaintext)

    # Close the writer
    $EncStreamWriter.Close()
    # Close the CryptoStream (pads and flushes any data still left in the buffer)
    $EncCryptoStream.Close()
    $EncMemoryStream.Close()

    # Read the encrypted message from the memory stream
    $Cipher     = $EncMemoryStream.ToArray() -as [byte[]]
    $CipherText = [convert]::ToBase64String($Cipher)

    # return base64 encoded encrypted string
    return $CipherText
}

$enc = [system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$string1 = "1234567890101212"
$key = $enc.GetBytes($string1)
$string = "123"

Encrypt-Rijndael256ECB  $key $string
pause
```

Вывод: zWbrs5FtqqRUtbjgKHsXMmjDtZ+itZU5yJF6z2MxxZM=

PHP (Apache 2.2. + php 7.1)

```
<?
$key = "1234567890101212";
$to_encrypt = "123";
$decrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $to_encrypt, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
echo ( base64_encode($decrypted) );
?>
```

Вывод: pmZ0YSUQMUd2O1WF2g4cMT4YBI80D3c6qL+tqSVZHCs=

И вообще, mcrypt_encrypt уже устарел.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mcrypt_encrypt` использует padding с нулями, а .NET по умолчанию ставит `PKCS7`. В павершел вам нужно добавить 1 строчку:

```
$RijndaelProvider.Padding = [System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode]::Zeros
```

Comment: Боже мой, вы мозг. Большое спасибо!